# The absolute uri: http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-9

Using jetty-maven-plugin. Got this error in the upgrade from jetty 8 to jetty 9.

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty 9 could not find sitemesh*.jar even though it was there.
So you have to add below code to your jetty-context.xml to make it work:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
    <Call name="setAttribute">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
        <Arg>^$|.*/sitemesh-[^/]*\.jar$</Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

Add all other jars names here which you want jetty to scan.